# Log all exceptions in .NET app using log4net

Tags: .net, log4net

Is there any easy way to auto write all the unhandled exception in my application to a log file?
I`m using log4net as my logging solution.

My application hosted as a windows service.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends on the type of application you are running. You should always register the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx#Y0) during startup of your application:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s, e) =>
{
    var exception = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
    // Log to log4net.
};
```

When using a ASP.NET application, you can hook onto the `HttpApplication.Error` event use the Global.asax to do this. When using a Windows Forms application you can hook onto the `Application.ThreadException` event.

Comment: I believe this should be AppDomain.CurrentDomain